# Error while creating DAG. Syntax error in DAG

Tags: airflow

I am trying to create a dag for running some query in hive using hiveoperator. Code is written below :

```
import datetime as dt

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.hive_operator import HiveOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 3, 24),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

hql_query = """USE testdb;
CREATE TABLE airflow-test-table LIKE test_table;"""

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='load-hive',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 * * * *'
)

hive-copy = HiveOperator(
    task_id="hive-copy",
    hql=hql_query,
    hive_cli_conn_id="dime_hive_cli_default",
    dag=load-hive,
)

hive-copy
```

I am getting syntax error:

> Can't assign to operator syntax error at hive-copy = HiveOperator(
>   line

. I am not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the dash '-' in hive-copy, rename it to hive_copy